# Spring 3: task namespace: How to find out time of next execution?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a bean that has a method executed on a schedule using `<task:scheduled>` in the context configuration.

Is there a way for me to find the time of the next scheduled run during execution of that method?

The same method is also executed manually, and the mechanism for receiving scheduler information may not break executions from outside the scheduler...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<task:scheduled>` configuration style is a convenient shortcut on to underlying Spring factory beans that generate schedulers and schedules. As a convenience, it's useful, but is much less flexible than using the underlying scheduler factories directly.

Having said that, the schedulers themselves would need to expose the "next fire time" information via their API, and that's implementation-dependent. For example, I don't see a way to get this information from the standard `ScheduledExecutorService` implementations.

Quartz, however, *does* expose this, via the `getNextFireTime()` method on the `Trigger` class.

If you're willing to abandon `<task:scheduled>` and [use the Quartz-Spring integration directly](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz), then you can get access to the `Trigger` (or `TriggerBean`) and get what you want that way.

Comment: The Spring Quartz integration is exactly where I went and it does what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For those not using quartz but spring, I have achieved to get next execution time by extending CronTrigger and remembering nextExecutionTime:

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger;

public class MyCronTrigger extends CronTrigger {
    public MyCronTrigger(String expression) {
        super(expression);
    }

    @Override
    public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
        Date date = super.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
        nextExecutionTime = new Date(date.getTime()); //remember
        return date;
    }
}
```